# Compress GPX file

Tags: qgis, export, gpx, compression, file-size

I have a .gpx file with a size of about 20MB. I want to load this file into a bicycle navigation application but somehow the file seems to be tool large. Are there ways to compress the file?

In QGIS I have the route as a MultiLineString, which I exported as .gpx.

[image: map]

Comment: maybe split them up into legs? something like http://www.gpstrackeditor.com/ can do this for you.

Comment: good suggestion but the goal really is to get the track as a whole so I don´t need to change between the tours.
Interesting program though.

Comment: What about simplifying the track? QGIS has the tool `Simplify` as well as the SAGA tool `Line simplification`.